# Weights minimization issue with linprog

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy, cvxopt

I am trying to use python (and at present failing) to come to a more efficient solution than Excel Solver provides for an optimization problem.

[Matrices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iflng.png)

The problem is the form A*B=C -->D
Where A*B produces C where the absolute value for C-D for each row in the matrix is minimized.

I have seven funds contained in **matrix B** all of which have geographic exposure of the form

```
FUND_NAME = np.array([UK,USA,EuroZone, Japan,EM,Apac)]
```

as below

---

```
RLS = np.array([0.788743177, 0.168048481,0,0.043208342,0,0])
LIOGLB=np.array([0.084313978,0.578528092,0,0.23641746,0.033709666,0.067030804])
LIONEUR=np.array([0.055032339,0,0,0.944967661,0,0])
STEW_WLDWD=np.array([0.09865472,0.210582713,0.053858632,0.431968002,0.086387178,0.118548755])
EMMK=np.array([0.080150377,0.025212864,0.597285513,0.031832241,0.212440426,0.053078578])
PAC=np.array([0,0.013177633,0.41273195,0,0.510644775,0.063445642])
PICTET=np.array([0.089520913,0.635857603,0,0.218148413,0.023290413,0.033182659])
```

---

From this I need to construct an optimal weighting of the seven funds using a matrix **(imaginatively named A)** [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7] with x1+x2+...+x7=1 & Also for i=(1,7)
xi lower bound =0
xi upper bound =0.25

To arrive at the actual regional weights (**matrix C**)as close as possible to the below Target array (which corresponds to **matrix D** above)

```
Target=np.array([0.2310,0.2576,0.1047,0.1832,0.1103,0.1131])
```

I've tried using libprog. But I know that the answer I am getting is wrong.

```
Funds =np.array([RLS,LIOGLB,    LIONEUR,STEW_WLDWD, EMMK,PAC,PICTET])
twentyfive=np.full((1, 7), 0.25)
bounds=[0,0.25]

res = linprog(Target,A_ub=Funds,b_ub=twentyfive,bounds=[bounds])
```

Can anyone help me move on from excel ?

Comment: It often helps to first write down a mathematical model of the problem.

Comment: I've put the matrix form above (its in a link as I'm a newbie). Hopefully that is clearer. Thanks.

Comment: There are basically two ways to model absolute values that are minimized: (1) variable splitting and (2) bounding. It is not too difficult to formulate your problem as an LP. `scipy.optimize.linprog` has a matrix interface which is always a bit cumbersome to use, but for this small and simple problem that should not be too much of an issue. If the problem becomes very large, one may have to pay attention to details (see [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2019/10/scipy-linear-programming-large-but-easy.html) for an example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a **LAD regression** problem (LAD=Least Absolute Deviation) with some side constraints. Different LP formulations for the LAD regression problems can be found [here](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/11/lp-and-lad-regression.html). Based on the sparse bounding problem, we can formulate the LP model:

[image]

This is the mathematical model I am going to try to solve with **linprog**. The coloring as as follows: blue symbols represent data, red symbols are the decision variables. *x* are the allocations (fractions) we need to find, *d* are the residuals of the linear fit and *r* are the absolute values of *d*.

**linprog** requires an explicit LP matrix. For the model above, this A matrix can look like:

[image]

With this it is no longer very difficult to develop a Python implementation. The Python code can look like:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as sp

B = np.array([[0.788743177, 0.168048481,0,0.043208342,0,0],
            [0.084313978,0.578528092,0,0.23641746,0.033709666,0.067030804],
            [0.055032339,0,0,0.944967661,0,0],
            [0.09865472,0.210582713,0.053858632,0.431968002,0.086387178,0.118548755],
            [0.080150377,0.025212864,0.597285513,0.031832241,0.212440426,0.053078578],
            [0,0.013177633,0.41273195,0,0.510644775,0.063445642],
            [0.089520913,0.635857603,0,0.218148413,0.023290413,0.033182659]]).T

target = np.array([0.2310,0.2576,0.1047,0.1832,0.1103,0.1131])

m,n = np.shape(B)

A_eq = np.block([[B,          np.eye(m),  np.zeros((m,m))],
                [np.ones(n), np.zeros(m), np.zeros(m)]])
A_ub = np.block([[np.zeros((m,n)),-np.eye(m), -np.eye(m)],
                 [np.zeros((m,n)),np.eye(m), -np.eye(m)]])

b_eq = np.block([target,1])
b_ub = np.zeros(2*m)

c = np.block([np.zeros(n),np.zeros(m),np.ones(m)])

bnd =   n*[(0,0.25)] + m*[(None,None)] + m*[(0,None)]

res = sp.linprog(c,A_ub,b_ub,A_eq,b_eq,bnd,options={'disp':True})

allocation = res.x[0:n]
```

The results look like:

```
Primal Feasibility  Dual Feasibility    Duality Gap         Step             Path Parameter      Objective          
1.0                 1.0                 1.0                 -                1.0                 6.0                 
0.3777262386888     0.3777262386888     0.3777262386888     0.6478228594143  0.3777262386888     0.3200496644143     
0.08438152300367    0.08438152300366    0.08438152300367    0.8087424108466  0.08438152300366    0.1335722585582     
0.01563291142478    0.01563291142478    0.01563291142478    0.8341722620104  0.01563291142478    0.1118298108651     
0.004083901923022   0.004083901923022   0.004083901923023   0.7432737130498  0.004083901923024   0.1049630948572     
0.0006190254179117  0.0006190254179117  0.0006190254179116  0.8815177164943  0.000619025417913   0.1016021916581     
3.504935403199e-05  3.504935403066e-05  3.504935403079e-05  0.9676694788778  3.504935402756e-05  0.1012177893279     
5.983549975387e-07  5.98354980932e-07   5.983549810074e-07  0.9885372873161  5.983549719474e-07  0.1011921413019     
3.056236812029e-11  3.056401712736e-11  3.056394819773e-11  0.9999489201822  3.056087926755e-11  0.1011915586046     
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.101192    
         Iterations: 8

print(allocation)

[2.31621461e-01 2.50000000e-01 9.07425872e-12 2.50000000e-01
 4.45030949e-10 2.39692743e-01 2.86857955e-02]
```

Comment: That is super. Thank you.